# MySQL How to select multiple rows with WHERE multiple columns on the same table?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to select `room_id` based on column `user_id` and `del`

| room_id | user_id | del |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 | 0 |
| 1 | 45 | 0 |
| 1 | 56 | 1 |
| 25 | 23 | 0 |
| 25 | 45 | 0 |
| 25 | 56 | 0 |

This is an example of my table, and I want to select room_id WHERE:

```
"user_id = 23 AND del = 0" (del of the row where user_id=23)
```

AND

```
"user_id = 45 AND del = 0" (del of the row where user_id=45)
```

AND

```
"user_id = 56 AND del = 0" (del of the row where user_id=56)
```

The query should only return `room_id = 25`
How do I achieve this with PHP or CodeIgniter?

I have tried using this and it's not working:

```
$this->db->select()
->from('table')
->where(['user_id' => 23, 'del' => 0])
->where(['user_id' => 45, 'del' => 0])
->where(['user_id' => 56, 'del' => 0])
->get()->result_array();
```

*Notes: it worked when I tried using join tables on the same table, but when I have 10 `user_id` (joining the same table 10 times), the query runs super slow (because it is a big table with almost close to a million rows).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `where` clause to filter matching rows, then group the results and add a having clause:

```sql
SELECT room_id
FROM t
WHERE (user_id = 23 AND del = 0)
OR    (user_id = 45 AND del = 0)
OR    (user_id = 56 AND del = 0)
GROUP BY room_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3 -- there are three rows with matching condition for that room
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
SELECT room_id
FROM table
WHERE user_id = 23 AND del = 0 AND user_id = 45 AND del = 0 AND user_id = 56 AND del = 0;
```

Then the query may look like this

```
$this->db->select('room_id')
->from('table')
->where(['user_id' => 23, 'del' => 0])
->orWhere(['user_id' => 45, 'del' => 0])
->orWhere(['user_id' => 56, 'del' => 0])
->get()->result_array();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but this doesn't work, have tried it

Answer (score 0):

You can either put all your `user_id`s in parentheses:

```sql
SELECT room_id
FROM table
WHERE (user_id = 23 OR user_id = 45 OR user_id = 56) AND del = 0;
```

or you can user the `WHERE IN` clause:

```sql
SELECT room_id
FROM table
WHERE user_id IN (23, 45, 56) AND del = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

"user_id = 23 AND del = 0" will add the Room ID 1 to the result set as well.
**Add a condition for room_id = 25 in the where clause.**

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT room_id
FROM
(
SELECT `room_id`,`user_id`,`del`,GROUP_CONCAT(user_id ORDER BY user_id ASC) ordered_user
FROM    `my_table`
GROUP BY room_id,del
HAVING ordered_user = "23,45,56" AND del=0
)
AS dbx
```

Explaination:

Your Data:

[image: This is Your Data]

Group by Room_id and Del
After that filter by HAVING in ordered_user
[image: After filter by having]

Make New dummy for only return 25

[image: Optional Step]

Answer (score 0):

An easier approach would be:

```
SELECT room_id
FROM table_tbl
WHERE user_id  in (23,45,56) AND del = 0 
GROUP BY room_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3 ;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/60